# Power of prime in prime factorization of a factorial.

Tags: elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers, factorial, prime-factorization

Please advise on how to arrive at solution for determining the power of 17 in the prime factorization of 2890!

Also, is there a short-cut?

So far I know:
Prime factorization of 2890 = 2 x 5 x 17^2

Thank you!

Comment: See [de Polignac's formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legendre%27s_formula)

Comment: Cf. [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3398690/find-the-exponent-with-which-5-is-among-the-1000); using your factorization, it's easy to divide $17$ and $17^2$ into $2890$ and see that $17^3>2890$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Hint:**  use your factorization to answer the following questions.

How many multiples of $17$ are there in the numbers up to $2890$ (which are multiplied to get $2890!$) ?

How many multiples of $17^2$ are there? (Each of these has an additional factor of $17$.)

Are there any multiples of $17^n$ for $n\ge3$?

Answer (score 1):

What I would do is think about all of the numbers between 1 and 2890 that are divisible by 17. Hence, those numbers would have 17 as a prime factor of themselves. Next, I would think about the numbers that could be represented as 17^2 x 2 x 5 or smaller while still having 17^2 as a prime factor. There are only 10 total numbers like that. Now you take the total number of numbers divisible by 17, subtract 10 from that,and add that number to 2 times the number of numbers divisible by 17^2 and that should be the power of 17 in the prime factorization for 2890!. I am not sure if this is correct and this is the first answer I have every answered but I hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

Between $1$ and $2890$, there are $170$ multiples of $17$, each of which contributes at least $1$ each to the exponent. Therefore, in $2890! = 17^x m^y$ (where $m$ is coprime to $17$, and we're not concerned with the value of $y$), it must be the case that $x \geq 170$.

Notice that in your factorization of $2890$ you have $17^2$, which is $289$. And since $17^3 > 2890$, each multiple of $17$ can't contribute more than $2$ to the exponent. Now, how many multiples of $289$ are there between $1$ and $2890$? Each of those contributes $2$ to the exponent, but we have already counted $1$ each in $x \geq 170$. So now we only need to add $1$ for each multiple of $289$.

If you have any doubt, [go to Wolfram Alpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=FactorInteger%5B2890%21%5D).