# Consider $f(n) = |\{ k \ |k \in \mathbb{N}, \ \frac{n^k}{k!} \in \mathbb{N} \}|$. Is this function related to the primorial?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, discrete-mathematics, prime-numbers

I was playing around with the term $\frac{n^k}{k!}$. Specifically, given a fixed n, I was wondering for which values of $k$ the term is an integer. Formally

Let $f: \mathbb{N} \rightarrow \mathbb{N}, f(n) = |\{ k  \ |k \in \mathbb{N}, \  \frac{n^k}{k!} \in \mathbb{N} \}|$

I wrote a quick python script to compute this:

```
def k_factorial_divisors(n):
    k, k_fac, n_k = 1, 1, n
    divisors = set()
    while k_fac <= n_k:
        if n_k % k_fac == 0:
            divisors.add(k)
        k += 1
        k_fac *= k
        n_k *= n

    return divisors
```

Running this for the first 500 integers yields:

```
print([len(k_factorial_divisors(i+1)) for i in range(500)])

# [1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 4, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 4, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 4, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 4, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 6, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 4, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 4, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 4, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 4, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 6, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 4, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 4, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 4, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 4, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 6, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 4, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 4, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 4, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 4, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 6, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 4, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 4, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 4, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 4, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 6, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 4, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 4, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 4, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 4, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 6, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 4, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 4, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 4, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 4, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 10, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 4, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 4, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 4, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 4, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 6, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 4, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 4, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 4, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 4, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 6, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 4, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 4, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 4, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 4, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 6, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 4, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 4, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 4, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 4, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 6, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 4, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 4, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 4, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 4, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 6, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 4, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 4, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 4, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 4, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 6, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 4, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 4, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 4, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 4, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 10, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 4, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 4, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 4, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 4, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 6, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 4, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 4, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 4, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 4, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 6, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 4, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 4, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 4, 1]
```

I wondered for which n we have $f(n) \gt f(m)$ for all $m \lt n$. Ie: when this function "jumps". A quick search yields:

$$f(1) = 1\\
f(2) = 2\\
f(6) = 4\\
f(30) = 6\\
f(210) = 10\\
f(2310) = 12$$

Similarly, there is a repeating pattern up to this new maximum, as can be seen by the first 210 digits

```
1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 4, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 4, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 4, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 4, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 6
1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 4, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 4, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 4, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 4, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 6
1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 4, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 4, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 4, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 4, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 6
1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 4, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 4, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 4, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 4, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 6, 
1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 4, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 4, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 4, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 4, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 6
1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 4, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 4, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 4, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 4, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 6, 
1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 4, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 4, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 4, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 4, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 10
```

1. These maximums seem to be exactly the primorials. Are they? Why?
2. The numbers seem to cycle, until the new maximum value is reached. Why?

Comment: Your code seems to be missing the case $k!=n^k$. Is it obvious that never happens?

Comment: It follows from the [Bertrand-Chebyshev theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bertrand%27s_postulate) that $k!$ is never a perfect power. (Consider the largest prime in $k!$.) But this theorem is not obvious.

Comment: Yeah it should be <=. It was fixed on my machine but not in the post. Updated.

Comment: By the same theorem, the largest prime in the interval $(0,n]$ is in the latter half, $(n/2,n]$, and thus doesn't divide $n$ (unless it equals $n$). You only need to take $k$ up to some prime not dividing $n$. Thus $k<n$, for $n>2$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will count the term $k=0$, thus adding $1$ to your $f(n)$.

If $n$ is odd, then there are only $2$ values of $k$ contributing to $f(n)$, as $n^0/0!$ and $n^1/1!$ are integers but $n^k/k!$ is not an integer for any $k\geq2$. Thus $f(n)=2$.

If $n$ is even but not a multiple of $3$, then there are $3$ values, $k=0,1,2$. Thus $f(n)=3$.

If $n$ is a multiple of $2$ and $3$ but not a multiple of $5$, then $k=0,1,2,3$ are certainly accepted, and any $k\geq5$ is certainly not accepted. But what about $k=4$?

$$n=6m$$
$$\frac{n^4}{4!}=\frac{2^4\cdot3^4}{1\cdot2\cdot3\cdot4}\cdot m^4=2^1\cdot3^3\cdot m^4$$

So this is also accepted. Thus $f(n)=5$.

If $n$ is a multiple of $2$ and $3$ and $5$ but not a multiple of $7$, then any $k\geq7$ is not accepted, and any $k<7$ is accepted:

$$n=30m$$
$$\frac{n^0}{0!}=1$$
$$\frac{n^1}{1!}=n$$
$$\frac{n^2}{2!}=\frac{2^2\cdot3^2\cdot5^2}{1\cdot2}\cdot m^2=2^1\cdot3^2\cdot5^2\cdot m^2$$
$$\frac{n^3}{3!}=\frac{2^3\cdot3^3\cdot5^3}{1\cdot2\cdot3}\cdot m^3=2^2\cdot3^2\cdot5^3\cdot m^3$$
$$\frac{n^4}{4!}=\frac{2^4\cdot3^4\cdot5^4}{1\cdot2\cdot3\cdot4}\cdot m^4=2^1\cdot3^3\cdot5^4\cdot m^4$$
$$\frac{n^5}{5!}=\frac{2^5\cdot3^5\cdot5^5}{1\cdot2\cdot3\cdot4\cdot5}\cdot m^5=2^2\cdot3^4\cdot5^4\cdot m^5$$
$$\frac{n^6}{6!}=\frac{2^6\cdot3^6\cdot5^6}{1\cdot2\cdot3\cdot4\cdot5\cdot6}\cdot m^6=2^2\cdot3^4\cdot5^5\cdot m^6$$

Thus $f(n)=7$.

We see a pattern. We expect that if $n$ is a multiple of $2\cdot3\cdot5\cdot7$ but not a multiple of $11$, then any $k<11$ is accepted (and it's obvious that any $k\geq11$ is not accepted) so $f(n)=11$. But can we prove that in generality? That is, if $p$ is any prime, and $n$ is a multiple of all primes less than $p$, then $n^k/k!$ is an integer for all $k<p$?

---

[Power of prime in prime factorization of a factorial.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3411493/power-of-prime-in-prime-factorization-of-a-factorial)

[Find the power of a prime in the prime factorization of a large factorial](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4082176/find-the-power-of-a-prime-in-the-prime-factorization-of-a-large-factorial)

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legendre%27s_formula

All we need from that formula is $v_q(k!)\leq k$, for primes $q$.

Suppose $p$ is a prime, and

$$n=m\cdot\prod_{\text{prime }q<p}q$$

is a multiple of the previous primorial. Suppose also that $k<p$, so any prime factor of $k!$ is less than $p$ and is thus a factor of the primorial.

$$\frac{n^k}{k!}=m^k\cdot\frac{\prod_q q^k}{k!}$$

Pick any particular prime $q<p$, and consider the $q$-adic valuation of this ratio (of primorial power to factorial). The other primes don't contribute, so it's the same as

$$v_q\left(\frac{q^k}{k!}\right)=v_q(q^k)-v_q(k!)$$
$$=k-v_q(k!)$$
$$\geq0$$

Therefore $n^k/k!$ is an integer.

---

In conclusion, we see that $f(n)$ is the smallest prime not dividing $n$.